# Empty column shows when using Hiddenfield in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a HiddenField in my GridView. A very small empty column appears, how can I get rid of the empty column?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateSelectButton="true">
        <Columns>                                           
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Song"  headertext="Song"/>                
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Album"  headertext="Album"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Artist"  headertext="Artist"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Genre"  headertext="Genre"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Price"  headertext="Price"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Explicit Lyrics"  headertext="Explicit Lyrics"/>
            <asp:TemplateField>                    
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SongID")%>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                            
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: If you want SongID ie ID then you can use DatakeyName OR if you still want hiddenfield Column.Apply CSS dispaly none to Header TExt and  template field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemplateField in GridView is meant to represent a field that displays custom content in a data-bound control and HiddenField used to store a non-displayed value.

You are creating a custom content column with a non-displayed value ,that leads to create a column with null as represented view for Front end. So If you want to fetch the value on selected index change of GridView then may use Following methods:

Method1: Use Datakey for grideview to store the datacolumn you want in your selecetedIndexchanged method:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateSelectButton="true" DataKeyNames="SongID">
        <Columns>                                           
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Song"  headertext="Song"/>                
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Album"  headertext="Album"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Artist"  headertext="Artist"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Genre"  headertext="Genre"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Price"  headertext="Price"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Explicit Lyrics"  headertext="Explicit Lyrics"/>                           
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

To access that key on SelectedIndexChanged Method :

```
int songId= Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Values);
```

Method2: Add hiddenfield within any column you have in your gridview not a special one for it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateSelectButton="true">
        <Columns>                                           
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Song"  headertext="Song"/>                
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Album"  headertext="Album"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Artist"  headertext="Artist"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Genre"  headertext="Genre"/>
            <asp:BoundField datafield ="Price"  headertext="Price"/>
            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Explicit Lyrics" >                    
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Lable runat="server" ID="lblexp" Text='<%# Eval("Explicit Lyrics")%>'>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SongID")%>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                            
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you welcome. is there any issues or error with method1?

Comment: I could not get method 1 to work. I was finally able to get it to work for me by changing Values to Value. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you added that hidden field to get id later. No need to add and hide a column. Use [datakey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

You could add this:

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
</style>
```

And adding these properties to the `asp:HiddenField` or `ItemTemplate` element
`ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"` and
`HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden` :) let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes, I can't test it now on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CellPadding and CellSpacing attributes of the GridView to zero:

```
<asp:GridView CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" ... >
```

If you still see the column you can set its width to zero:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="0" HeaderStyle-Width="0" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

On Gridview RowDataBound function add the below code to hide the columns you want.

Eg:

In the aspx,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

In code behind,

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[cellno.].Visible = false;
    } 
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[cellno.].Visible = false;
    }
}
```